# How to run the python code with limit number in for loop?

Tags: python

I have a simple for loop code for calculate the sum of all multiples of 3 & 5 less than 100, and since I place the print under the if, it will shows all the sum of multiples of 3 & 5, and I want it only shows the sum of 3&5 before 100, what should I do? thanks.

```
range(1,100)
total = 0
for i in range(1, 100):
    if i % 3 == 0 or i % 5 == 0:
        total += i
        print(total)
```

Comment: The indentation doesn't look right. The for loop has an empty block without an explicit `pass`.

Comment: Make sure the indentation you show us here matches the indentation of the code you're running. Currently it does not make sense.

Answer (score 1):

If I interpret your question correctly, you're asking how to only print the sum at the end, not at every point in the loop.  The answer to this is to de-indent the `print` statement to be outside the `if` and `for` blocks:

```
range(1,100)  # note: this line does nothing, you can remove it
total = 0
for i in range(1, 100):
    if i % 3 == 0 or i % 5 == 0:
        total += i
print(total)
```

You can compute this sum more simply with the `sum` function:

```
print(sum(
    i for i in range(1, 100)
    if i % 3 == 0 or i % 5 == 0
))
```

Answer (score 0):

If what you are trying to ask is to print the total only once and not again and again, then the answer is simple, just unindent the line with the print statement, that is:

```
total = 0
for i in range(1, 100):
    if i % 3 == 0 or i % 5 == 0:
        total += i
print(total)
```

This is because, if the statement is indented, it will be treated as a part of the for loop and will run on every iteration of the for loop. Instead, unindent it to make it run only once and that is after the for loop is done running. The output for this code will be like this:

[image]

Comment: You don't need to quote the question when answering. Also please add your results as text, not a picture.

Comment: the question had some problems which seem to now be edited, that is why I had added the question.

Comment: Then it should be a separate comment on the question - if you can't try to edit the question.